# JQuery UI resizable can't cancel resize programmatically

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have been trying to create a resizable div using JQuery UI which will also resize a table contained within the div.

```
$("#WorkRequests").resizable({
        minWidth: $("#WorkRequests").width(),
        maxWidth: $("#WorkRequests").width(),
        handles: 's',
        resize: function (event, ui) {
            var minRows = 10;
            var rowHeight = 35;
            var rows = $("#tbl-WorkRequests-page-size").val();

            if ((rows * rowHeight) > $("#WorkRequests").height()) {
                if (rows > minRows) {
                    $("tbl-WorkRequests-page-size").val((rows - minRows).toString());
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

However when they resize the div to be too small so that it reaches "return false;" it does not cancel the resize event like with other JQuery ui things. Why?

Also the below line:

```
$("tbl-WorkRequests-page-size").val((rows - minRows).toString());
```

Should set the value of a select list, however it does not, why?

Comment: Hi Alex! Can you please post the html code for this. Thanks :)

Comment: It would be better if you could post the HTML as well. At least the relevant bits. If return false doesn't work, have you tried changing the minHeight value inside the `resize` method? This would hook jqueryUIs own check methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out on this line

```
$("tbl-WorkRequests-page-size").val((rows - minRows).toString());
```

I was missing the #, sorry guys, I should have posted the html.

```
$("#tbl-WorkRequests-page-size").val((rows - minRows).toString());
```

Thanks,
Alex.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: This is not possible because draggable is not correctly implemented. return false should stop the event, but unfortunately this is not correctly implemented for resizable.